# Youtube Width and Height

Tags: facebook, youtube-api

a)Can I check is there a default width and height that is set by Youtube when a public try to share the video to Facebook ? 
b)Or user can set the width and height of the video when they upload the video to Youtube?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a video, facebook or youtube, there a default height and width... but it's not resizable in none of them. **Now** if you embed a facebook or youtube video inside your own website you can adjust width and height as you want it.

Comment: User will just enter the URL from my website and when they click on a Share button, the video url will be shared to Facebook. Thus I am doing the programming portion in sending the meta tag to Facebook to handle. And the video:width and video:height are mandatory fields.